# copy folder of svn repository to a folder in another repository

Tags: subversion

My server details are as follows

- centOS 6
- subversion 1.6
- svn paths: `/var/www/svn/repo1`, `/var/www/svn/repo2`

I have a repo1 which has directory trunk inside it.
repo1--->trunk

I have another repo2 which has trunk and in trunk i have X and Y folders now i need to copy X and Y folders to repo1 trunk folder.

i used following command

```
svn copy file:///var/www/svn/repo2/trunk/X file:///var/www/svn/repo1/trunk/
```

it shows following error

```
svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///var/www/svn'
```

How can I copy it?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the [documentation for Subversion 1.7](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.copy.html) (you have 1.6, which is less capable):

> **You can only copy files within a single repository. Subversion does not support cross-repository copying.**

If you want to copy files/folders, you can either

- check out from repo 1, copy the working files/folders and add them and check them into repo 2 (like any other content), or
- dump the files/folders with history and load them into another repository.  See for example *[How to copy SVN repository as a folder to another repository with history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795887/how-to-copy-svn-repository-as-a-folder-to-another-repository-with-history)*